# Erro ao introduzir dados na BD usando mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou a tentar inserir em 2 tabelas dados, mas tenho sempre o erro de 
`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` ou seja isto quer dizer que não consegue inserir na segunda tabela, porque na primeira a **PK** ainda não existe.

Eu fiz assim:

```
 $insere_um = "INSERT INTO utilizadores(n_processo,nome,password,id,cod_grupo)
  VALUES('".$n_processo."','".$nome."','".$pass."', '".$tipo['id']."', '".$grupo['cod_grupo']."')";


  if(!mysqli_query($conexao,$insere_um))
  {
    echo mysqli_error($conexao);
  }
  else
  {

    $insere_dois = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO utilizador_modulos(codigo_ut_mod,n_processo,cod_modulo) 
    VALUES
    ('".$n_processo."1',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod1_001['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."2',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod1_002['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."3',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod1_003['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."4',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod1_004['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."5',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod1_005['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."6',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod2_001['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."7',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod2_002['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."8',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod2_003['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."9',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod2_004['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."10',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod2_005['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."11',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod3_001['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."12',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod3_002['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."13',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod3_003['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."14',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod3_004['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."15',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod3_005['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."16',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod4_001['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."17',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod4_002['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."18',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod4_003['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."19',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod4_004['cod_modulo']."'),
    ('".$n_processo."20',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$sql_mod4_005['cod_modulo']."')"
    );
  }
```

Comment: Interpretação estranha essa que vc fez da mensagem de erro: _"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ou seja isto quer dizer que não consegue inserir na segunda tabela, porque na primeira a PK ainda não existe."_ - poderia dizer como chegou nessa conclusão para entendermos melhor a dúvida?

Comment: De curiosidade, pq vc ta fazendo a `insere_um` 2 vezes, uma vez no if e outra no else? Acho que assim vai ficar dificil funcionar. Seria legal você aprender a fazer as coisas mais básicas antes, esse código seu tá muito complicado pro tipo de erro que está comentendo. Vá aos poucos, degrau por degrau, que ajuda a dominar as etapas, senão acumula muito lugar pra depois achar o problema.

Comment: Eu costumo complicar aonde não existe @Bacco :) Mas essa conclusão surgiu porque tive já me tinha acontecido antes este erro porem funcionou desse jeito mas com o mysql normal em vez de mysqli. Também encontrei várias pessoas com o mesmo erro, e disseram que se tratava disso. Isto é uma parte do código inteiro, basicamente o que preciso é de saber o que se costuma fazer quando é preciso inserir dados em 2 tabelas ligadas

Comment: Quanto ao _"Eu costumo complicar aonde não existe @Bacco"_ fique sossegado, que praticamente todo ser humano domina essa arte de complicar :)  - Só mencionei, pq de repente o problema é bem mais simples, e é importante você não confiar em analisar uma possibilidade só e esquecer de outras. Provavelmente a inserção dupla já está atrapalhando você. Experimente tirar a segunda ocorrência, no else. e veja se muda o problema/erro.

Comment: Verdade @Bacco :p. Mas eu ja tinha experimentado isso, daí pus assim para tentar, mas não deu. So insere os dados na primeira tabela :\

Answer (score 0):

Eu só achei estranho uma coisa, você usa no primeiro INSERT a variável $n_processo, entretanto, no segundo INSERT você concatena $n_processo com mais um carácter, será que não é isso que esteja fazendo o script dar o erro para realizar a inserção?

Comment: Isso foi uma forma que eu arranjei para ser a chave primária da segunda tabela. usando a primária da tabela anterior com um "incremento". :) Mas esse não é o problema.

Comment: Mas esse deve ser o problema, se na tabela 1 o registro tem a chave primária com o valor 10, ele tem que se relacionar na tabela 2 com o valor 2, do contrário, eu creio que não vai existir um vínculo entre os registros.

Comment: Já consegui meter a funcionar, apenas troquei o `LAST_INSERT_ID()` para `$n_processo` que é a chave primária da primeira tabela e FK da segunda. Mas o `LAST_INSERT_ID()` supostamente não fazia o mesmo?

Comment: Da maneira que você usou não iria dar certo, ele precisa saber de qual tabela ele vai solicitar a chave primária.